# Rendering Problem in IE8 with richFaces and JSF empty text node

Tags: java, css, jsf, internet-explorer-8, richfaces

I have a form of the following type:

```
<rich:dataList var="var" value="#{bean}" styleClass="styleClass"><h:form>
 <h:commandLink value="#{var.prop}" action="#{bean.action}">
      <a4j:actionparam name="var" value="#{var.id}" assignTo="#{bea.sel}" />
 </h:commandLink>
```

Now, this is all fine in Firefox and IE 7. However, in IE 8 it creats empty text-nodes just before the link. I tried fixing it with the css.

```
form {
   display: block;
   zoom : 1;
}
```

This did help to render it correctly in IE 7. However, the empty text nodes are still created an cause problems with iE 8.

Comment: Empty text nodes are always present in HTML files (except in earlier IEs due to bugs). What makes you think empty text nodes are a problem?

Comment: Apparently, there is a line break which IE8 interprets as an empty node. Does anybody know how to alter the generated code, such that it has no more line breaks?

Comment: @bobince I used the developerTool in IE8 to take out the text nodes manually and then it started rendering corectly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Removing `display: block;` should fix the issue for you.  IE turns this into an empty text node when it's marked as a block.